# Trying to use Append To File raises AttributeError exception

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to append data stored in a variable to a file. The file was successfully created and the data is stored in the variable; however, I continue to get the AttiributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

here are my results

```
KEYWORD ${FileA} = OperatingSystem . Create File metrics/Live_RTT.txt, ${MT_Com_RTT_LB_Live_Topics}
00:00:05.233 KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Click Element ${BLANK_CANVAS}
00:00:05.129 KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Click Element //div[@title='${device1}']
00:00:05.063 KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Click Element //div[@title='${device2}']
00:00:00.045 KEYWORD ${MT_Com_RTT_LB_Live_Topics} = Selenium2Library . Get Text xpath=${REAL_TIME_TRENDING_TOPICS}
00:00:00.001 KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log ${MT_Com_RTT_LB_Live_Topics}
Documentation:  

Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20181028 21:37:34.971 / 20181028 21:37:34.972 / 00:00:00.001
21:37:34.971    INFO    Available Topics
Active Energy Delivered + Received
Active Energy Into the Load
Active Energy Out of the Load
Active Power
Active Power A  
00:00:00.001 KEYWORD OperatingSystem . Append To File ${FileA}, ${MT_Com_RTT_LB_Live_Topics}
Documentation:  

Appends the given content to the specified file.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20181028 21:37:34.972 / 20181028 21:37:34.973 / 00:00:00.001
21:37:34.973    FAIL    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the library's source, the exception most probably is raised in the `normalize_path()` method, which does this string replacement:

```
    path = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser(path.replace('/', os.sep)))
```

, where `path` is the filename - the first argument to the `Append To File` kw call. The exception says its value is `None` (e.g. no value set) while it should be some string.

Looking at the log, you're setting this value to the return value of `Create File` - but that keyword does not return one at all, it simply creates the file you specified in its first argument.
So to resolve - just set the value of `${FileA}` yourself, pass it to the two keywords, and do not reassign in the `Create File` call.